# Is there a way to have music player using Nuxt3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to add audio player to my website and i added player: new Audio () to data return but i keep getting this error `[nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] ReferenceError: Audio is not defined` does anyone know what i am doing wrong??

Here is my full code

```js
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            current: {},
            index: 0,
            isPlaying: false,
            progress: 0,
            songs: [
                {
                    title: 'Sample Song',
                    artist: 'Sample Artist',
                    src: '@/assets/audio/sample.mp3',
                },
    ],
            player: new Audio()
        }
    },
```

A repro is available here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hwdvrl?file=src%2FApp.vue

Comment: I never used `new Audio()` but do you know how it works in a regular JS context? Is it even needed here? Can't you run `play` on a music format?

Comment: @kissu I have it playing now but it keeps jumping songs here is my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hwdvrl?file=src%2FApp.vue

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, an even is sent once the song is done running, you could probably pause at that time. Even tho, the default behavior is probably nice as is. Do you expect a music player to stop playing after the first song is done?

Comment: @kissu i want it to play the next song accordingly without jumping tracks. Do you know a solution for this??

Comment: Not sure of the exact issue but something is wrong with the index change overall, if you spam it you break the app. Try to maybe make a better usage of Vue's reactivity or use a `watch` to let it update itself rather than with conditionals. Also, try to use the Vue devtools to debug this one efficiently.

Comment: @kissu the song player works fine but the exact issue is that when you click play and you allow the first song to finish playing, it moves to the second song (after the second finish playing) it jumps the third song to the fourth song which is wrong. Which means it does not play the song accordingly from the third song on the list.